# automatically close pylint window after python code window is close in VIM

Tags: linux, vim, pylint, python-mode

How can I set automatically close pylint window after python code window is close in VIM?

Every time I quit from vim, but pylint window still displayed.

I want to automatically close pylint warning window when I quit from python code.

I know the way to doing this by manually is `:qa!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the pylint window shows a scratch buffer, you can close this automatically via an `:autocmd`:

```
:autocmd WinEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && ! empty(&buftype) && ! &modified | quit | endif
```

When you `:quit`, you either exit Vim or enter another open window. Above checks that this is a single window containing a scratch buffer with unpersisted changes, and then quits that, too. This should give you the general idea; you can tweak the conditions to better suit your needs.

Comment: Handy link for those not familiar with autocmd: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html